# Choosing a font for text

Tags: font

I am trying to decide on fonts to use for my website. While I do this I need a easier way to choose between fonts. And I need to see how my title, menu items look in the fonts I choose. I am looking for a quick reference tool that can help me decide between multiple fonts. But I know thats a long shot, so instead I am hoping to find a website that helps me choose between fonts for my specific text.

Doing this in word and photoshop can be very painful and time consuming. Is there a website that helps choose between fonts, while seeing your own text ?

Comment: Siddharth, please review our FAQ. You've now asked several questions in a row that have been closed as not a real question or off-topic. If you need help interpreting the FAQ or want to know more about what kind of questions are appropriate for UX, feel free to join the chat and we'll help you out.

Comment: Sure. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other web font outlets like typekit.com provide a similar ability to preview fonts; I like the TypeKit interface because of the additional filtering controls it provides.

If you're looking beyond just web fonts, a lot of foundries (houseind.com is a favorite) and resellers (myfonts.com, veer.com) offer similar preview capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just found www.google.com/webfonts. Works like a charm. Any more recommendations ?

Comment: Looks like you should edit the question instead of answer the question and then ask iteratevly.

Comment: Well, I read through the FAQ, and answering your own question is encouraged. Also this question seems valid too. But for some reason Rahul thought it to be off topic. After reading the FAQ I still wonder. Its a valid question. Google webfonts is so helpful. Saves so much time. The downvoters did not bother to tell me why I was downvoted also.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopefully its better now.